# How to hard refresh using Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have various ways in Selenium like `driver.navigate().refresh();` and `driver.execute_script("location.reload()")` to do refresh, but these perform normal refresh. I want to hard refresh my page, is there any way to hard refresh the page using Selenium.
The code in any of Java/Python would be welcomed.

Note: I don't want to use Robot class to perform it, so please provide any other way to do it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**A Regular** refresh may reload the page from its cache.

**A Hard** refresh reloads from the server, not from cache.

---

If you wish to delete the Cache too use `Cache.delete()`:

see [MDN Web Docs on Cache.delete()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/delete).

---

## The answer:

You can use `location.reload(true);` with `execute_script`:

```
driver.execute_script("location.reload(true);")
```

> Reloads the resource from the current URL. Its optional unique parameter is a Boolean, which, when it is true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache.

For more info see [MDN Web Docs on Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That code is only correct if you are using Firefox.. According to the linked documentation, any other browser ignores all parameters passed to location.reload(). Trying to find an alternative, but wanted to save time for any future readers.

Comment: See more info... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload