# How do I clear local storage on remote webdriver session

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browserstack, remotewebdriver

I am running selenium on remotewebdriver that connects to browser stack to run tests on different browsers. the thing is i have three @Test in my code and at the end of each test the URL is loaded again so I land on the home page again. In Chrome, the first test passes, the second test fails as the previous selection from the first test is remembered in the local storage. Then the 3rd test passes again as the local storage is cleared. In firefox all tests are passing.

I have tried with the code i have pasted in this ticket - i have put it @AfterMethod class in my setup. it clears the local storage in all the tests except no.2 in chrome. without this code, all of the tests are failing except the first one. someone please advise and sorry if it doesn't make sense.

```
 final RemoteExecuteMethod executeMethod = new RemoteExecuteMethod((RemoteWebDriver) driver);
        final RemoteWebStorage webStorage = new RemoteWebStorage(executeMethod);
        final LocalStorage storage = webStorage.getLocalStorage();
        storage.removeItem("sessionState");
```

I am not sure how to make the code more stable. Any ideas.

Comment: Is this not just an issue with cookies, you can clear the cookies after each test which should remove any previous states.

Comment: @StephenK we don't have cookies so we have to clear the local storage

Comment: Did you try `storage.clear()`?

Comment: @Guy yes tried this. doesn't change anything.

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54571878/8179099) helpful