# Java&Selenium&Firefox/Chrome: unable to press CTRL + F5 for page hard refresh

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

Please see my code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.navigate().to("https://example.com");
Thread.sleep(5_000);

driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.F5);
Thread.sleep(5_000);

driver.quit();
```

Page should be refreshed, but it never happened.
I tried different ways to write code to perform key press but no luck.

---

UPDATE

As mentioned below in comments, it's possible to reload page with `driver.navigate().refresh()` method.

I need perform Hard refresh in order to make proxy rotation. `driver.navigate().refresh()` method works well with Firefox, but not with Chrome.

Anyone able to do hard refresh in Chrome?

Comment: why don't you refreshed the page via `driver.navigate().refresh();`

Comment: @KunduK I thought that method `refresh()` will call regular refresh (F5). I was need hard refresh (Ctrl + F5). You are right, it solved my issue.

How I can choose your comment as answer?

Comment: Happy to help you.

Comment: Check out this link, It will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571696/how-to-hard-refresh-using-seleniumhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571696/how-to-hard-refresh-using-selenium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to make it work, you have to use the **Action** class in Selenium.

**For Chrome in Windows:**

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);   
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.F5).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

**Other hacks using JavascriptExecutor:**

The reload() method is used to reload the current document. The reload() method does the same as the reload button in your browser. By default, the reload() method reloads the page from the cache, but you can force it to reload the page from the server by setting the forceGet parameter to true: location. reload(true).

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("location.reload(true);");
```

**Ref:**

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/keyboard/

Comment: Thank you for you comment.

Approach with Actions does not work, it same thing that I did but with different syntax. Tested in Firefox and Chrome.

But JavaScript works well.

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly my setting cause of not working short keys. But it would be strange. I'm using my setup for over 3 year without any spotted issues.